# Dynamic loading of WebAssets in Webview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I have a requirement that I need to create a webview dynamically where the web assets are stored online as a zip. On load of my mobile I need to download the file and unzip it and load it in the webview. For this, I have written the code. I am able to download, unzip and get the file access but, could not load it in the UI. Please look into my code and help me where I am wrong. Also, is it possible the load the assets of web dynamically or only with static approach it can be possible?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class MyWebViewUsingInAppWebview extends StatelessWidget {
@OverRide
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Webview Example'),
),
body: InAppWebView(
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('about:blank')),
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController webViewController) async {
await downloadAndUnzipFile(webViewController);
},
),
);
}

Future downloadAndUnzipFile(
InAppWebViewController webViewController) async {
String zipFilePath =
'files/forms-td-practice.zip'; // Replace with your zip file path

try {
  firebase_storage.Reference ref =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(zipFilePath);

  String downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();

  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File localFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/example.zip');

  // Download the zip file to the local file system
  await ref.writeToFile(localFile);

  print('Zip file downloaded successfully! Saved to: ${localFile.path}');

  // Unzip the file
  String unzipPath =
      appDocDir.path; // Unzip to the app's documents directory
  List<int> bytes = localFile.readAsBytesSync();
  Archive archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

  for (ArchiveFile file in archive) {
    String fileName = '${unzipPath}/${file.name}';
    if (file.isFile) {
      File outFile = File(fileName);
      outFile.createSync(recursive: true);
      outFile.writeAsBytesSync(file.content);

      // If the current file is "index.html", load it into the WebView
      if (file.name == 'forms-td-practice/forms-td-practice/index.html') {
        webViewController.loadUrl(
            urlRequest:
                URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('file://${outFile.path}')));
      }
    }
  }

  print('Zip file extracted successfully!');
} catch (e) {
  print('Error downloading/unzipping file: $e');
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about try to read a file as string and load the string via   `loadHtmlString`

```
var htmlString="YOUR_HTML_STRING"
    webViewController.loadHtmlString(htmlString);
```

also make sure u enable javascript if you are using any.

Comment: Yes the way you suggested is working. But, I dont only have index.html, also css and js files. So, I need to read the contents of all the files and add them as inline in HTML and load the HTML content in webview which for the larger codebase might cause performance issue while reading the contents.